# Are there famous deities/gods or spiritual supremo, who had a daughter?

Tags: gods, marriage, women, culture, children

In India, culturally boys are preferred over girls as a child by many orthodox families. Such attitude creates kind of deep rooted gender bias and certain wrongful activities like abortion or discrimination.

So I was wondering, how can such culture evolve? Why don't they look towards their god/deity as an example?
While iterating myself on various gods or saints or spiritual supremos, I was bit astonished to notice that many of them did not have a biological girl child (exclude Brahma).
This doesn't infer any bias, but it was naturally the situation. BTW, in old times also, the people used to seek for sons, possibly for *Pitru-runa*.

In a chronological order (not the full list):

- Lord Śaṅkara (a Rudra) has 2 sons
- Lord Hanumān possibly has sons only
- Śri Rāma had 2 sons
- <strike>Vasudeva had all sons from Dēvaki & another wife</strike>
- Veda Vyāsa through Niyōga had 3 sons
- Śri Kṛṣṇa had all sons from 8 of his wives
- Other Mahābhārata personalities like Drōṇa, the Pāṇḍavas also had son(s)
- Mahātma Gāndhi, a saintly figure of modern era also had 4 sons

**Are there any famous godly figures (who are worshipped or revered), who had a daughter?**
Though not hard-presses, but non-mythological persons are preferred.

Comment: Janaka- Sita; Himalaya- Ganga, Uma; Daksha Prajapati- 31 daughters like Sati and Rohini,(Padma Purana hints Lord Shankara too has daughter called AshokSundari), Incarnation of Adi Shakti in various form like sister of Krishna (Yogamaya), Kanyakumari etc... can be examples

Comment: @Tezz, Janaka came to my mind first as well. But is he (or other examples) considered among the godly figures? Haven't seen people worshipping them. Though there is a mention of similar name in Bhagavad Gita.

Comment: Ashoka sundari is said to be the daughter of goddess Parvati and eventually Shiva also.- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ashokasundari

Comment: non-mythological persons but  godly figures the combination is rare.

Comment: @SwiftPushkar, yes that's why I am not hard pressed on "non-mythical". But still I would be more interested about personalities from the [religious] *'itihAsa'*-s like Ramayana, Mahabharata etc. BTW, you may mention the Ashokasundari in the answer if it's considered a godly figure.

Comment: @iammilind - Yes Ashok Sundari is worshiped as Bal-Tripursundari in south. And even 'itihAsa'-s like Ramayana, Mahabharata will be also narrating the tales mostly of gods , but one possibility is that some Rishi's who became elevated to godly positions might  have daughters. :-)

Comment: @iammilind - Also take a look at this. https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/18909/5620

Comment: famous deities or simply deities? @iammilind

Comment: @Rickross, "famous deities" was my preference. However, as of now I see that there are not any. So you may mention "deities" as well. They should be at least worshiped.

Comment: BTW found one case of Rishi Renu who's daughter is Goddess Renuka , wife of Jamdagni rishi and mother of Parashurama. But Rishi Renu is nighter godly fig. and nor worshiped but his daughter is . Just a close case. - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Renuka

Answer (score 9):

From creation chapters of various Puranas, we find that there were more daughters than sons. For example,

- Svāyambhuva Manu (the father of mankind) had 3 daughters (Ākūti, Devahūti and Prasūti) and 2 sons (Priyavrata and Uttānapāda). (**SB 4.1**)
- Daksha Prajapati had many daughters who are mothers of other creation. Although, Daksha had few sons but we don't find their names as they didn't have genealogical table.

So you can see that there was no gender discrimination in the beginning.

Other examples are

- Indra had daughter named Jayanti
- Surya had daughter named Yami
- Lord Ganesh had daughter named Santoshi (though hard to find references in early scriptures)
- Shukracharya had daughter named Devayani
- Himalaya had daughters: Uma, Ganga
- Janka (Rajrishi) and his brother had daughters: Sita and her sisters
- Vasudev had daughter named Subhdra

---

Above all are famous godly figures who are either worshipped or revered.

Comment: Nice to see that, you have listed many examples. However, are those worshipped? Why citing "sisters"?

Comment: You mentioned "Mahabharata personalities like Drona" so mentioned Dusla..(I thought of mentioning Kripacharya's sister Kripi and Drupad's daughter Draupadi as they were related to Drona closely:) )...and if Gandhi is in ur example then why not Janka who was known as Rajrishi...other than that who is not worshipped? @iammilind

Comment: Probably you have got the Qn wrong. I am neither seeking for popular goddesses who are worshipped nor famous personalities who are having daughters nor the sisters of gods. I took example for few other Mahabharat characters and Gandhi**ji**, because those were spiritually enlightened or revered. Though this answer has mix of real & mythical characters, I would recommend to put source [link] alongside to evaluate. Btw if you make this a wiki, then you are allowing others to edit to better & to remove irrelevant parts. You may not find it fair. If you are not Ok then, flag to Mod to remove wiki.

Comment: 'I am neither seeking for popular goddesses who are worshipped nor famous personalities who are having daughters' - then you should remove the word 'famous' from the title. It's misleading. @iammilind

Comment: @sv., the question is about "famous *gods/spiritual-heads* who had daughters" and Not about "famous **people** who had daughters". For example, as noted in SwifPushkar's comment -- Rishi Renu is a famous person who had daughter, but he is not worshipped in popular culture. Now, if we consider the famous south actor Rajinikanth, who is worshipped by people in an almost god-like way, then he can be listed, because he has 2 daughters. However, an actor like him will be too off-beat for our site. Hope that clears the doubt.

Comment: @iammilind in the above list who is neither worshipped nor revered? Or are they not famous?

Answer (score 1):

There are two most popular and one of the most revered sages who had goddesses as daughter.

Rishi Bhrigu, and Rishi Katyayana.

#### 1. Rishi Bhrigu

Bhrigu is one of the most exalted sages, son of god BrahmA.

In one of the creations, Goddess Lakshmi manifested as Rishi Bhrigu's daughter.

> Vishnu Purana [1.10.2a](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/vishnu-purana-wilson/d/doc115946.html)
>
> पराशर उवाच:
>
> भृगोः ख्यात्यां समुत्पन्ना लक्ष्मीर्विष्णुपरिग्रहः ॥२.क॥
>
> > Parāśara said:—
>
> > 2. **Lakṣmī, the bride of Viṣṇu, was the daughter of Bhrigu by Khyāti.**
>
> English Translation by H.H. Wilson

---

### 2. Rishi Katyayana

Rishi Katyayana (कात्यायन) is also a popular sage. The great goddess manifested from the potencies of several gods in his hermitage, and hence she's called Katyayani (कात्यायनी), as per the Vamana Purana.

Although, not biological daughter, but she's still popularly referred as Rishi Katyayana's daughter sometimes.

> [Verse 18.7,9](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.313087/page/103/mode/1up?view=theater)
>
> तच्चैकतां पर्वतकूटसन्निभं जगाम तेजः प्रवराश्रमे मुने ।
> कात्यायनस्याप्रतिमस्य तेन महर्षिणा तेज उपाकृतं च ॥ १८.७ ॥
> तेनार्षिसृष्टेन च तेजसा वृतं ज्वलत्प्रकाशार्कसहस्रतुल्यम् ।
> तस्माच्च जाता तरलायताक्षी कात्यायनी योगविशुद्धदेहा ॥ १८.८ ॥
>
> > 7. O sage, **the light coming out from the bodies of these gods, in the form of a peak of a mountain, became united in the *ashrama* of the
> >    unequalled Katyayana rishi. The great sage augmented it with a lustre
> >    of his own.**
>
> > 8. Being augmented with the lustre of the Rishi, the combined lustre appeared as effulgent as a thousands sun shining at a time. From it
> >    was born the charmingly beautiful Katyayani with a body rendered holy
> >    by the practice of Yoga.
>
> English Translation by Swarupananda Gupta

---

## tl;dr:

- Although both the goddess are eternal, and have no birth (their birth is but a *leela*), but for the sake of argument presented in the question, they maybe considered as the "daughters" of the respective Sages.
- Thus, Bhargavi from Rishi Bhrigu, and Katyayani from Rishi Katyayana, maybe considered two examples of famous revered personalities with worshipped daughters.
- On a side note, [in some folkloric accounts](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/24085/which-scriptures-describe-abhimanyus-marriage), Balarama is also said to have a daughter named Vatsala or Shashirekha, who married Abhimanyu. Interestingly, Balarama refers Duryodhan as his son-in-law in the [Markandeya Purana](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/45035/how-is-duryodhana-a-son-in-law-to-balarama). How is that made possible, that I'm yet to establish in truth.