# How is Duryodhana a son in law to Balarama?

Tags: puranas, duryodhana, balarama, markandeya-purana

I was reading Markandeya Purana and found that there is a mention of Duryodhana being a son in law of Balarama. I am not able to find more information about this in Markandeya Purana. I am looking for information on how Duryodhana became the son in law of Balarama and who was Balarama's daughter in this story. The below quote is taken from [Canto VI - Baladeva’s brahmanicide of Markandeya Purana](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-markandeya-purana/d/doc117032.html).

> The plough-armed Rāma,
> knowing the perfect affection of Kṛṣṇa for Arjuna, deliberated
> much—“Can what has been done be better done? Without Kṛṣṇa, assuredly,
> I will not go near Duryodhana; or how, siding with the Pāṇḍavas, **shall
> I slay king Duryodhana, my royal son-in-law and disciple?** Therefore I
> will go neither to Arjuna nor to king Duryodhana. I will myself bathe
> myself at holy bathing places, so long as it conduces to the ending of
> the Kurus and Pāṇḍavas.”